# Choosing a Document Class

Tags: document-classes

I'm a high school math teacher and use latex to make all of my worksheets, tests, reviews, and handouts. I haven't really used any other document class besides article, but I know that there are a lot of other document classes out there. Are there any suggestions for which document class would be best for writing worksheets and quizzes?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the [exsheets package](http://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) for my worksheets. I used some other packages/classes before this but I think it's the best and feature-full.

Last year I created own (simple) class with my specific needs (with many helps from tex.stackexchange :) ) based on exsheets.

Comment: Okay, cool! I'll have to check that package out. What are some of the exsheets specific features that you use a lot?

Comment: I like the "Variations of an Exam" feature. You can easily style, can use some question from a "database", etc. And this project is active :)

Comment: Plus "feature": the (included) tasks package is very useful too :) You can use multiple columns (without any "workaround"), span columns, etc.